# Python as CGI script for HTML form action

Tags: python, cgi, rsync

We are trying to create a web page to take some inputs for file to be fetched to server.
Form action is specified as python script.The python script imports a file transfer script which fetches file to specified destpath using rsync.

We have all our scripts with test permissions(instead of root).
We observe that rsync is not getting invoked when called via the html.
But same rsync is working fine when the python script is called directly instead of 'form action' of HTML page.

how to resolve this?

Comment: show your code. add `print()` to see what's going on in script when you call it. web server may run as different user, with different environment and different privilages.

Comment: Yeah we have print statements.It has got something to do with previliges.

Comment: is there a way to know from what account a html file executes on Ubuntu server?

Comment: if you use Apache or Nginx server then it use (mostly) user `www-data`

Comment: Ok got it.Thanks! there was no read/write permission for this user.Provided permissions with 'chmod 777' to destination path.Then it worked